# PHP mailer (message body empty)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new to PHPMailer and I want to send an HTML mail with this class. But I Get the message that the body is empty.

This is my code:

```
<?php        

$bericht .= 'my html and php code that format the mail';

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$bericht);

$mail->SetFrom('email@adres', 'Name');

$address = "email@adres";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to display your `$body` to make sure it really contains something? maybe something is wrong before (e.g., in the part that fills the `$bericht`)

Comment: Consider using `<?php` instead of `<?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your `preg_replace()`. If I try to run this on my server I get this warning:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 3

Did you try the code without the `preg_replace()`, i.e., just by passing `$bericht` to `MsgHTML()`?

Comment: That's it, strange because it comes directly from the phpmailer example file :)

Comment: escape the [ character, like preg_replace('/\\[\\]/','',$bericht)

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an error in you code

```
$bericht .= (my html and php code that format the mail);
```

should be

```
$bericht = 'my html and php code that format the mail';
```

and then instead of this

```
$body             = $bericht;
$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);
```

its easier to do this

```
$body             = preg_replace('/\[\]/','',$bericht);
```

Comment: try printing or echo'ing body to see what it holds

Comment: I made a change to my code, check it, you need to escape the [ character, copy the line where you use preg_replace, should work now

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstand why you need to do this INCREMENT with the variable if it has no need.

```
$bericht .= ...;
```

And yes, where's the string value within quotes right in there?